# Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I tried to run the following code but it returned this erros:
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ''1'' in 'field list'' in /home/cardg/cards/jogar.php:59 Stack trace: #0 /home/cardg/cards/jogar.php(59): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /home/cardg/cards/jogar.php on line 59
Why this is happening?

```
<?php

 include('config.php');


$usuarion = $_SESSION['login'];
$senhan = $_SESSION['senha'];

// $attrs is optional, this demonstrates using persistent connections,
// the equivalent of mysql_pconnect
$attrs = array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true);

// connect to PDO
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbservidor.';dbname='.$dbnome.'', $dbusuario, $dbsenha);

// the following tells PDO we want it to throw Exceptions for every error.
// this is far more useful than the default mode of throwing php errors
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// prepare the statement. the place holders allow PDO to handle substituting
// the values, which also prevents SQL injection
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT estado,usuario1,usuario2,usunivel,id  FROM duelos WHERE estado=:estadox AND usuario1!=:usuario");

// bind the parameters
$stmt->bindValue(":estadox", 0);
$stmt->bindValue(":usuario", $usuarion);

// initialise an array for the results 
$duelos = array();
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $products[] = $row;
        echo $row['usuario1'];
    }
}



$usuario = $pdo->query("SELECT id,apelido,usuario,nivel FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '".$usuarion."' AND senha ='".$senhan."'");
$usulinha = $usuario->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$usuarioid = $usulinha['id'];
$usunivel - $usulinha['nivel'];

    $sqlduelos = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM duelos WHERE (estado = 1 AND usuario2 = 0)";

       if ($resl = $pdo->query($sqlduelos)) {
    /* Check the number of rows that match the SELECT statement */
  if ($resl->fetchColumn() > 0) {
  $msg = "True msg";
    }
    else{
        $msg = "false msg";

        $inid = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `duelos`  (`usuario1`, `usunivel`)  VALUES (
    `:usua`,
    `:usuni`)");

    $inid->bindParam(':usua', $usuarioid);
    $inid->bindParam(':usuni', $usunivel);
    $inid->execute();

    }
}

// set PDO to null in order to close the connection
$pdo = null;

    ?>
```

Comment: Remove the backquotes around `:usua` and `:usuni`

Comment: Please add a comment to show us where line 59 is in the file

Comment: @rsanchez Error changed to:
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'usunivel' cannot be null' in /home...

Comment: My advice: you don't seem to master enough basics of databases to accomplish this task, I suggest you go do some reading first.  The above error just means that you cannot insert something in `duelos` without specifying a value for `usunivel`.  What you should specify depends on what the designer of the schema intended to go there, but as the schema specifies `NOT NULL`, something should go there...

Comment: @fvu line 59 is the $inid->execute();

Comment: For the second error: where you've got `$usunivel - $usulinha['nivel'];` you probably mean `$usunivel = $usulinha['nivel'];` (equals, not minus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove delimiters (backticks) around the placeholders:

```
$inid = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `duelos`  (`usuario1`, `usunivel`)  
   VALUES (:usua, :usuni)");
```

... as these are *placeholders*, which values (bound to them by `bindValue`) will be escaped automatically. Otherwise, those values will be treated as a column names, causing the error.

As a sidenote, you have a typo here:

```
$usunivel - $usulinha['nivel'];
```

... it should be `$usunivel = $usulinha['nivel'];` most probably.

Comment: But that doesn't mean this piece of advice is wrong, as it fixes the problem given in the question, doesn't it? Then you catch up with another error in your code - but the point is, that's _another_ error. And while the former problem is indeed interesting (I remember answering another question when someone decided that it's a good idea to place `'` around placeholders), the latter is just a typo - that should have been caught by proper setting of `error_reporting` level.